# Embedding an object detection model into iOS app, and deploy it on a UIView's content instead of camera stream?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tensorflow, coreml

I've retrained an ssd_mobilenet_v2 via tensorflow object detection API on my custom class. I've now got a frozen_inference_graph.pb file, which is ready to be embedded into my app. 
The [tutorials on tensorflow's github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/ios) and website only show how to use it for the iOS built-in camera stream. Instead, I have an external camera for my iPhone, which streams to an UIView component. I want my network to detect objects in this, but my research doesn't point to any obvious implementations/tutorials.

My question: Does anyone know whether this is possible? If so, what's the best way to implement such a thing? tensorflow-lite? tensorflow mobile? Core ML? Metal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In that TensorFlow source code, in the file **CameraExampleViewController.mm** is a method `runCNNOnFrame` that takes a `CVPixelBuffer` object as input (from the camera) and copies its contents into `image_tensor_mapped.data()`. Then it runs the TF graph on that `image_tensor` object.

To use a different image source, such as the contents of a `UIView`, you need to first read the contents of that view into some kind of memory buffer (typically a `CGImage`) and then copy that memory buffer into `image_tensor_mapped.data()`.

It might be easier to convert the TF model to Core ML (if possible), then use the Vision framework to run the model as that can directly use a `CGImage` as input. This saves you from having to convert that image into a tensor first.